# Ember JS - Cannot read property 'save' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

In a nutshell, I have created a record ("claimant") in the model hook of a route, but when I try to get the "claimant" record in the actions handler, Ember says the record doesn't exist. As a result, when I try to save "claimant," Ember tells me that it "Cannot read property 'save' of undefined." My guess it is a problem with my initializer, but I'm stumped as to why.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated. Thanks!

The relevant code is as follows:

models/claimant.js

```
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default DS.Model.extend({
first_name: attr('string'),
submission: DS.belongsTo('submission', {async: false}),
});
```

models/submission.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default DS.Model.extend({
claimant: belongsTo('claimant', {async: false}), 
});
```

routes/claimant.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
actions: {
    next: function() {
        let claimant = this.get('claimant');
        claimant.save().then(claimant => {
            this.get('submission').createSubmission({
            claimant: claimant
            });
        });
        this.transitionTo('defendant');
    },
},

model() {
    let claimant = this.get('store').createRecord('claimant', {
        first_name: this.get('first_name'),
        });
    return claimant;
}
});
```

NOTE: If I instead use let claimant = this.get('controller.model'); the record saves properly, but then the BelongsTo relationship between "submission" and "claimant" doesn't properly set. Not sure why.

initializers/submission-initializer.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const {isNone, isEmpty, merge} = Ember;

let submissionProxy = Ember.ObjectProxy.extend({
_currentSubmission: null,
_store:null,

content: function() {
    let currentSubmission = this.get('_currentSubmission');

    if (isEmpty(currentSubmission)) {
    currentSubmission = this.createSubmission();
    }
     return currentSubmission;
    }.property('_currentSubmission'),

current: Ember.computed.alias('content'),

createSubmission(data = {}) {

    let newSubmission = this.get('_store').createRecord('submission', data);   
    this.set('_currentSubmission', newSubmission);
    return newSubmission;
},
});

export function initialize(application) {
application.register('submission:proxy', submissionProxy, {singleton: true});
application.inject('submission:proxy', '_store', 'service:store');
application.inject('component', 'submission', 'submission:proxy');
application.inject('route', 'submission', 'submission:proxy');
application.inject('controller', 'submission', 'submission:proxy');
};

export default {
name: 'submission-initializer',
after: ['ember-data'],
initialize: initialize
};
```

templates/claimant.hbs

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome to the Claimant Page!</h2>

<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
  {{input id="first_name" class="form-control" value=model.first_name}}
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'next' model}}>Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm pretty noob to EmberJS, but I think the variable 'claimant' that you define in 'let claimant = this.get('claimant');' is literally being set to undefined. Hence you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Two things - 
A) use this.get('model').save in your action (claimant is being returned by the model, but in your action, you have no way to access the local variable that is defined within the model - i.e. 'claimant')

B) In your model, first_name: this.get('first_name') will not work --> you might want to define a variable in your route and tie that to the input field in your hbs file and then access that variable in your model.

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Thanks @Chhirag Kataria! Two quick questions: 1) I tried using this.get('controller.model') before and calling save. This works (it persists the model to the backend), but the BelongsTo relationship between 'claimant' and 'submission' does not get set when I do so. As a result, when I save the 'submission model,' the backend shows the relationship as undefined. Any thoughts? 2) Can you clarify what you mean in B) of your comment? I'm not sure how that varies from my current code. Thanks!

Comment: @MathewAndrews Yes, this.get('controller.model') saves on the backend because you are essentially accessing the model to do it, which equals to what I have in (A). I am not sure what you mean by the relationship not getting set properly though - I looked at your code, not sure why you have this.get('submission').createSubmission... what is createSubmission, and what is this.get('submission')?

(B) talks about you accessing this.get('first_name')  directly - where is it defined?

Comment: Thanks @Chhirag Kataria When I say the relationship is not getting set properly, I mean that when I save both the 'claimant' model and the 'submission' to the backend server, the backend tells me that the two are not related to each other. The BelongsTo property shows up as null. Any idea why that's the case?

Comment: @MathewAndrews try changing claimant: belongsTo to claimant: DS.belongsTo

Comment: @MathewAndrews also, I don't know if this is the complete code or not, but there seems to be a lot of general issues with how you have set up everything - as in my previous comment, there are several things which are undefined. I'd say take a closer look and refer to the docs extensively.